# Checking for invalid values inside 2d array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is there a way to set a 1-13 restriction for the first column and a 1-4 restriction for the second column

My output looks like this:

The card value and suit that you've chosen are:

1  2

3  4

5 6

7 8

9 10

This is my code  so far, i know that the while loop affects all values in my 2d array. I am stuck as to how I'll set two different restriction As for my inputs right now it only accepts values between 1 - 13

```
void getCard(int card[][2])

{

int i, j;
printf("\nPlease enter the card value followed by its suit\n");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &card[i][j]);

        while (card[i][j] > 13|| card[i][j] < 1)
        {
            printf("\nOnly enter card value between 1 to 13.\n");
            scanf("%i", &card[i][j]);
        }
    }
 }

 }

void main(void)
{
int i, j;
int card[5][2];

getCard(card);

printf("\nThe card value and suit that you've chosen are:\n");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
    {
        printf("%i  ", card[i][j]);
        if (j == 1)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please put input, expected output, and actual output as text in the question itself. Not as an image, not as a link, and definitely not as a link to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like:

```
for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)//loop by columns
{
    int rest=13;//for the first column
    if (j==1)
        rest=4;//for the second column
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    scanf("%i", &card[i][j]);
        while (card[i][j] > rest|| card[i][j] < 1)//the loop depends on the value of rest
        {
            printf("\nOnly enter card value between 1 to %i.\n",rest);
            scanf("%i", &card[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

if you need to go through the rows anyway:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)//loop by rows
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)        
    {
    int rest=13;//for the first column
    if (j==1)
        rest=4;//for the second column
    scanf("%i", &card[i][j]);
        while (card[i][j] > rest|| card[i][j] < 1)//the loop depends on the value of rest
        {
            printf("\nOnly enter card value between 1 to %i.\n",rest);
            scanf("%i", &card[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```